# C# grpc server-side only certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, grpc, .net-5

Anyone know of an example on how to configure grpc to use a server-side only certificate (not the default dev certificate)?
So no client certificate, just a server side one to encrypt the channel.

I created a self-signed pfx and imported it to the trusted root certification authorities.
Using the following configuration atm:

```
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(x =>
                    {
                        x.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate;
                        x.ServerCertificate = GetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.CertificateAuthority, "<thumbprint>");
                    });
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

  "profiles": {
"Aeternum.ServiceHost": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:15425",  //the pfx was created for localhost
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}

  "Kestrel": {
"Url": "https://*:15425",
"EndpointDefaults": {
  "Protocols": "Http2"
}
```

Trying it with this client (I'm pretty sure ChannelCredentials.Insecure is not correct, but I don't know what else to do there):

```
        var channel = new Channel(rootUri.Host, _rootUri.Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
        return new AuthServiceV1.AuthServiceV1Client(channel);
```

Currently I'm getting this exception at client-side (without ssl everything seems to work fine):

Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1628428855.871000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1628428855.871000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution.

Server:

```
  "CertThumbprint": "<certificate thumbprint>",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Url": "https://*:15425",
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  },

        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(x =>
                {
                    var thumbprint = context.Configuration["CertThumbprint"];
                    x.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate;
                    x.ServerCertificate = GetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.CertificateAuthority, thumbprint);
                });
            });
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

In the client, don't create the channel yourself, but instead use the grpc client factory:

```
    services.AddGrpcClient<AuthServiceV1.AuthServiceV1Client>((sp, o) =>
        {
            var configuration = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var serviceUrl = configuration["ServiceUrl"];
            o.Address = new Uri(serviceUrl);
        })
        .AddInterceptor<ClientInterceptor>();

services.AddTransient<AuthService>();
```

And finally the service class itself:

```
    public class AuthService
    {
        public AuthService(AuthServiceV1.AuthServiceV1Client client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        private readonly AuthServiceV1.AuthServiceV1Client _client;

        ...
    }
}
```